# Identify TVS diode model

Tags: diodes, identification, tvs

I guess that's a TVS diode, but I can't figure out what model it is. I tried to search on Google for 'z749' but there were no results.

It's from an Einhell 18v battery board.

[image: img2]

[image: img1]

Comment: Well, it's clearly an ST part, so a good starting point might be looking through their catalog. Examine the circuit around it to figure out what its likely purpose is (is it a zener? a TVS diode? something else?), then look for parts ST makes that do that.

Comment: It would be very helpful to figure out what package it is also. Is it an "SMB" diode? Are you able to measure the package dimensions with calipers? From the reference designator, I guess it is a TVS. So I would look at transient voltage suppressor products first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is clearly from STMicroelectronics, and has the lot/date code printed on it as "Z749" but only "MM" for the identification. From most ST datasheets, in Table 6 of [this one](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sm6t100a.pdf), you can see how this provides the necessary information printed on the package to identify it from other other TVS parts they make.

This is the SM6T24CA. Its a TVS DIODE 20.5VWM 42.8VC SMB. Digi-Key part number 497-7434-1-ND.

Here is the Table 6:
[image]